# Need help joining 2 tables and rolling them up in a unique way using BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables at different granularity in a BigQuery dataset. I need to join those two and roll it up using BigQuery SQL in such a way that the value in one of the columns of the 2nd table becomes the columns in the final table

Table 1 - tb1 looks like this

```
user_id     event_date
A          2019-02-01
B          2019-02-10
C          2019-01-15
```

Table 2 - tb2 looks like this

```
user_id    activity_id   activity_date
A          1             2019-01-01
A          1             2019-02-05
A          2             2019-01-15
B          2             2019-02-02
B          3             2019-02-01
C          1             2019-01-02
```

I am trying to write a SQL query to create the final table which tells us the number of records for each activity for a user_id where the activity_date is within (event_date - 90 days) for that user_id i.e the activity_date is in the 90 days leading up to the event_date.
So, in this case, the output will look like this

```
user_id   event_date  act_1   act_2    act_3 
A         2019-02-01   1        1        0
B         2019-02-10   0        2        1
C         2019-01-15   1        0        0
```

act_1 column corresponds to activity_id=1 and so on.

There are some additional complications like :-

- 1. The number of distinct activity_ids in Table 2 can change over time. So, I don't know before hand how many columns will be created in the output table.
- 2. I cannot do this in python but has to be done in BQ. This is because the actual table 2 is very large (42TB with 31bn rows) and pulling it out of BQ into another GCS product to run python might be cumbersome.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I created a table with the list of all activity_ids and then wrote the below code to use them to create a list of column names.  
```
SELECT concat('activity_',regexp_extract(json,'{activity_id:([^\\]]*)}'))
FROM
(
SELECT REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '"','') AS json
FROM 
(
select activity_id from activity_list
) as t
)
```

But i got stuck after that. Really not sure what to try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and just to demonstrate you approach of pivoting data

If you would know in advance how many distinct activity_id you have and if the number of such is low - for example three - as in your example - you would do as simple as below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  user_id,
  event_date,
  COUNTIF(activity_id = 1) act_1,
  COUNTIF(activity_id = 2) act_2,
  COUNTIF(activity_id = 3) act_3
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1
JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2
USING(user_id)
GROUP BY user_id, event_date
ORDER BY user_id, event_date
```

if to apply to sample data as in your question - result will be

```
Row user_id event_date  act_1   act_2   act_3    
1   A       2019-02-01  2       1       0    
2   B       2019-02-10  0       1       1    
3   C       2019-01-15  1       0       0
```

But as you mentioned

> The number of distinct activity_ids in Table 2 can change over time. So, I don't know before hand how many columns will be created in the output table

So, you need to generate above query dynamically - below is an example of such

```
#standardSQL
WITH activities AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT activity_id 
  FROM `project.dataset.table2`
), generate_query AS (
  SELECT CONCAT(
    'SELECT user_id, event_date',
    STRING_AGG(CONCAT(',COUNTIF(activity_id = ', CAST(activity_id AS STRING), ') act_', CAST(activity_id AS STRING)), ''),
    ' FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1 JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2 USING(user_id) GROUP BY user_id, event_date ORDER BY user_id, event_date'
  ) AS query
  FROM activities
)
SELECT query FROM generate_query
```

Again, if to apply to your sample data - result will be

```
SELECT user_id, event_date,COUNTIF(activity_id = 1) act_1,COUNTIF(activity_id = 2) act_2,COUNTIF(activity_id = 3) act_3 FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1 JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2 USING(user_id) GROUP BY user_id, event_date ORDER BY user_id, event_date
```

if to look closer to above result - you can see  - it is exactly the query that we initially wrote manually - but now it was generated for us - and no matter how many distinct activity_id you have (obviously limitations on columns number is still apply) - it will product needed query

So, now you just need to copy the text of query from above result and just simply run it - which will produce desired result

```
Row user_id event_date  act_1   act_2   act_3    
1   A       2019-02-01  2       1       0    
2   B       2019-02-10  0       1       1    
3   C       2019-01-15  1       0       0
```

As you can see this is two-steps process - but you can script it using client of your choice

Note: i focused on substance of the question and have not addressed at all 90 days related stuff - I feel it was secondary detail in your question

Comment: Amazing! this works. You are right that the 90 day detail is not really part of the challenge I am facing and I can incorporate that using where clauses. Will figure out best way to execute on a schedule but this solves my main problem. Thank You!